# Table Prefix Using Castle Active Record

Tags: castle-activerecord

Is there anyway to add a prefix to table names at configuration time using Castle Active Record?

```
[ActiveRecord("Address")]
public class Address : ActiveRecord<Address> {}
```

I'd like the actual table created/referenced to be "PRODAddress" or "DEBUGAddress".  Is there anything built-in like that I am not seeing?

Thank you,

[EDIT]  I've marked the general answer below, but here is the actual code to implement table prefixes for Castle Active Record:

```
...
ActiveRecordStarter.ModelsCreated += ActiveRecordStarter_ModelsCreated;
ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, typeof(Address));
...

private static void ActiveRecordStarter_ModelsCreated(ActiveRecordModelCollection models, IConfigurationSource source)
{
    string tablePrefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TABLE_PREFIX"];
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tablePrefix)) return;

    foreach (ActiveRecordModel model in models)
    {
        model.ActiveRecordAtt.Table = String.Format("{0}{1}", tablePrefix, model.ActiveRecordAtt.Table);
    }
}
```

Comment: added to the ActiveRecord FAQ: http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecordStarter.RegisterExtension(IModelBuilderExtension extension)](http://erichauser.net/2008/07/09/advanced-activerecord-models-part-2/) or the [ActiveRecordStarter.ModelCreated](http://alexscordellis.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-sqlite-for-fast-database-testing.html) event

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to [configure](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/manual/xmlconfigref.html) your own [INamingStrategy](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html)