# Is it possible to configure default settings on Castle Activerecord attributes?

Tags: attributes, castle-activerecord

Is it possible to configure the default settings on Castle Activerecord attributes? For example, I'd like all strings to have length 4001 (which makes it a `nvarchar(MAX)` on SQL Server) without having to put `Length=4001` on every `[Property]` attribute. I'd also like all collections to be lazy-loaded without having to put `Lazy=true` on every `[HasMany]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588360/table-prefix-using-castle-active-record). You can use the same mechanism to programmatically inspect and change the ActiveRecord model before it's passed to NHibernate.